# Javascript websocket asynchronous no sleep

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, websocket

I am from a firmware background and primarily write code in normal procedural C.

Currently I need to get a Web Browser to connect to some hardware via a dedicated TCP socket and exchange data in a custom protocol format. We have elected to go the Websockets route as this technology works on new phones,PC's and tablets.

My problem is that Javascript has no true Sleep() function. Normally we would do something like this:

1. send a message.
2. Sleep whilst the hardware processing the message.
3. Get the response and continue running program.

For example, I would like to save some data to hardware.

1. send data in protocol.
2. get the response confirming the hardware saved the data.
3. if successful send message A else send some message B.

The problem is step 3 cannot be done since there is no Sleep. I have read about the setTimeoutfunction() but this does not solve my problem. It seems to messy to have the callback event handle each received packet and jumping to different functions. Also, if i had a whole lot of sends in a while loop, this seems impossible with the callback functions?

I understand my approach may be wrong but can anybody explain to me how to adjust my reasoning to handle this situation?

Any comments or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: have you looked at jquery's deffered object stuff? http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/  basically will queue things up based on success or failure of a prior step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use sleep to wait for Websocket response even if there was one in javascript. Using sleep would hang your whole site in wait for socket response. By hang I, for example mean, no interaction from user.

To deal with endless callbacks You need to do some design first, not just throw them here and there.

Canonical way of doing this is to register one handler for (Web)socket which is called when server sends You a message. Your application remembers internally it's state (read about state machines) and knows what to do with this message, in this point of execution it currently is.

BTW. If Your flow is only as You've written to ask server and wait for response, please consider using simple AJAX. WebSocket is designed to allow server to push messages to receiver when it(server) decides to, not only to answer explicit request. AJAX was designed for this use-case and you can call it synchronously so make Your program linear even without sleeps ;)

Comment: I kind of reached the same conclusion as a state machine. It just seems a bit messy having a huge callback for every send. Also, the code becomes split so following the its path is more complex :(                          I cannot use AJAX since my server is actually a microcontroller and the number of sockets is restricted to one. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You definitely come from a firmware background :) - Callback functions are very common in Javascript and are very easy to write because the language is more functional than it's object-oriented. Callbacks are everything but messy in JS.

Comment: @user1689007 I don't know if we understand each other well ;) You write one callback for messages from server. This callback act's as some kind of router which decides where to direct your execution basing on the current state and type of message from server. IMHO it is more elegant than having sequences of ask - answer communication. For instance how do You handle error or exception in this sequential approach? With one common router You do it in one place.

Comment: @yakxxx, I understand there is only one callback. Its just that the callback must now route for every occasion I need to process the response and do something. I think it is an elegant a solution. In fact, I did a similar thing for a touch screen device in C to handle touch events. It seemed so tedious keeping track of code flow. Was hoping there was an alternate solution I am not seeing.

Comment: AJAX would definitely be the proper solution but unfortunately my hardware is a micro-controller.  There is no server. It simulates the responses of a real server. We need to use our custom protocol so that there is no need to do processing of AJAX requests by the firmware server. This will allow for our web server to behave the same as our standalone software suite as far as the micro-controller was concerned. If there is a change in the future, we don't need to issue new firmware, we could just update the web pages and JavaScript. This keeps the software and firmware nice and separated. :)